# How to Launch local url on Cobalt master 16

Tags: launch, cobalt

I want to use cobalt to launch local html page, So how can I launch local page by Cobalt 16 master.

Sunch as `./cobalt --url=xxxxxxx`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should have tried solving the problem on your own first before asking on Stackoverflow. To give you just a small hint, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

Use the --web_file_path commandline argument to set the directory for the local content, in conjunction with --url to specify the start page.

Example:
./cobalt --web_file_path=/home/content_folder --url=file:///index.html

(Note the three /// is required)

This will load the page: /home/content_folder/index.html
Works on any non-gold build.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So how to set the web_file_path in the code and work on gold build. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Run a local web server and point Cobalt to it using `--url=http://localhost:xxxx`. This will work in all Cobalt configurations and will allow you to specify HTTP headers (for example, `Content-Security-Policy`) should you need them. Same-origin policy will work as expected as well, so you'll be able to access resources such as images and style sheets.

Comment: We don't have a local web server, we only want to launch the local page.Before master16,we use js extension and specify the parameter kSbSystemPathSourceDirectory(/content/dir_source_root----System_get_path),so we can put our page in this dir, and use --url=file:///index.html to launch local url. But at master16, the parameter can't be used, so how can I specify the dir which save the page and images \ style sheets, and make the page can work on the gold version. Thank you very much.